# Redux - What is the point of normalizing the data

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm struggling with the concept of normalizing the data in Redux.

For example, if we normalize the following data:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "author": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Paul"
  },
  "title": "My awesome blog post",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": "324",
      "commenter": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nicole"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

to this:

```
{
  result: "123",
  entities: {
    "articles": { 
      "123": { 
        id: "123",
        author: "1",
        title: "My awesome blog post",
        comments: [ "324" ]
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "1": { "id": "1", "name": "Paul" },
      "2": { "id": "2", "name": "Nicole" }
    },
    "comments": {
      "324": { id: "324", "commenter": "2" }
    }
  }
}
```

And in my template, I need to loop over the `posts` and show the `post.comments`, for example in Angular -

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
    {{post.title}}
    <div *ngFor="let post of post.comments">...</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to do some transformation to get back this structure. Otherwise, I can't display the data in my page,  **So what is the whole point**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [redux docs have a pretty detailed section on this topic](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape) but the main reasons are:

> This is a concern for several reasons:
>
> - When a piece of data is duplicated in several places, it becomes harder to make sure that it is updated appropriately.
> - Nested data means that the corresponding reducer logic has to be more nested or more complex. In particular, trying to update a deeply
>     nested field can become very ugly very fast.
> - Since immutable data updates require all ancestors in the state tree to be copied and updated as well, and new object references will
>     cause connected UI components to re-render, an update to a deeply
>     nested data object could force totally unrelated UI components to
>     re-render even if the data they're displaying hasn't actually changed.

From personal experience, I can say that the third point can deliver significant performance improvements in some situations.

Comment: So what u are saying is that this is a good practice to normalize and denormalize the state?

Comment: Not exactly.  It's a practice that is best in some situations (like the ones listed in the answer) to help you overcome some common issues. If you aren't having problems, don't worry about it.

Comment: Author of the "Structuring Reducers" docs here.  Yep, normalization is considered a good practice for Redux-based apps, but not a requirement. Not sure how things work with Redux+Angular, but in React-Redux connected components define a `mapStateToProps` function that extracts the data needed for that component. For normalized data, you'd usually have an array of IDs, map over that array, and retrieve the corresponding items by their IDs.

Comment: @markerikson so in my example, you will map the posts with the comments?

Comment: Yeah.  I'll throw together a quick example as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked, here's an example of how you might look up the Comment entries for a given Post:

```
const mapState = (state, ownProps) => {
    let currentPost, postComments;

    if(ownProps.postId) {
        currentPost = state.posts[postId];

        if(currentPost) {
            const {comments : commentIds} = currentPost;
            postComments = commentIds.map(commentId => state.comments[commentId]);
        }
    }

    return {currentPost, postComments};
}

class Post extends React.Component { /* component code here */ }

export default connect(mapState)(Post);
```

This would then be used as `<Post postId={123} />`.

Comment: But now Post can't be a dumb component because it's use connect.